# Closing Stream by terminating program - Common practice?

Tags: java, io, stream

I have an Audioplayer that implements `Runnable`. It starts a sound and terminates afterwards. Is this a common practice or should I close it afterwards by myself, like in the last method, that isn't used currently. In my opinion it's a good idea to just let it terminate and force-close the rest automatically.

```
public class AudioPlayer implements Runnable {

    AudioInputStream audioIn;
    Clip clip;

    public AudioPlayer (String res) {

        try {
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource(res);
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        clip.start();
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            clip.close();
            audioIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Do* release resources explicitly as soon as they're not needed anymore!

Comment: Do you intend to call `run()` more than once on a single instance of `AudioPlayer`? If not, you could/should include the call to `close()` in the `run()` method.

Comment: @GhostCat :P...

Comment: Just wondering : what is the reason for the un-accept?

Comment: @GhostCat I saw that u removed all of your comments, so I was curious what you would do if I remove the acceptance, lol. Sorry. Useless "Social Experiment". B-)

Comment: Let me know what the scientific evaluation of the outcome of the experiment  brings up in terms of new discoveries. You see, in the end this is a question/answer community. It is all about the questions and answers. Thus I try to cleanup everything that doesn't contribute to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question: no, that is not **common** practice, but bad practice!

In general it is bad practice to acquire resources and to not explicitly release them. Especially for streams - there might be file handles behind that, all kinds of stuff. Just opening them and throwing them away might work; but as said: simply bad practice. And note: for any kind of program that is intended to run longer periods of time ... it is not only "good" to release resources, it is an absolute **must** to do so.

Especially when one considers that Java 7 introduced try-with-resources years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Either open the streams in the `run()` method and close them in a finally clause, or implement `AutoCloseable` so that your class can be used as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to free memory/resources just after using it, for this, exists `finally` block:

```
public AudioPlayer (String res) {
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(res);
        audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioIn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}
```

But, If your audio stream closes automatically when finished, you don't need to force close if not an error:

```
public AudioPlayer (String res) {
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(res);
        audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioIn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: To be extra sure to clean up everything, you may want to write it like:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
        clip.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        audioIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```